# vue component data and computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am having the following issue.

I am declaring data and i want to setup before, current and day after.

```
data () {
  return {
    notes: {
      ...
    },
    view: {
      dayCurrent: new Date(),
      dayBefore: new Date().setDate(this.view.dayCurrent.getDate() - 1),
      dayAfter: new Date().setDate(this.view.dayCurrent.getDate() + 1)
    }
  }
}
```

But once I save this i am getting following error

> Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dayCurrent' of undefined" as if my view object does not exist.

Why is this? How do I setup this and avoid this kind of error.

Comment: Why not just use `new Date.getDate` instead of `this.view.dayCurrent`?

Comment: please check my updated answer i did some changes like using directly the constructeur of Date not the `setDate` method

Comment: This occurs because you're trying to reference the object you're currently initializing. Ana Liza Pandac's answer is correct because it removes this circular reference during initialization.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to declare `dayCurrent` outside the `return` statement and reference it in your other properties.

```
data () {
  const dayCurrent = new Date();
  return {
    notes: {
      ...
    },
    view: {
      dayCurrent: dayCurrent,
      dayBefore: new Date().setDate(dayCurrent.getDate() - 1),
      dayAfter: new Date().setDate(dayCurrent.getDate() + 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works. I am getting the timestamps but it works. Thanks.

Comment: your suggested solution is fine but you should add `()` to `getDate` method and use directly the constructeur instead of `setDate` method

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thanks for `getDate` headsup, I missed that one. However, as for using the `Date` constructor directly would lead to this date `1970-01-01T00:00:00.027Z`.

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac yes currently i faced that when i test it in my browser console, sorry

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim No worries.

Comment: please check my answer i fixed that

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to initialize your `view` property in mounted hook as follows :

```
data() {
    return {
      notes: {
        ...
      },
      view: {
        dayCurrent: '',
        dayBefore: '',
        dayAfter: ''
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.view.dayCurrent = new Date();
    this.view.dayBefore = new Date(this.view.dayCurrent.getDate() - 1);

    this.view.dayAfter = new Date(this.view.dayCurrent.getDate() + 1)

  }
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      notes: {

      },
      view: {
        dayCurrent: '',
        dayBefore: '',
        dayAfter: ''
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.view.dayCurrent = new Date();
    let d1 = new Date().setDate(this.view.dayCurrent.getDate() - 1);
    this.view.dayBefore = new Date(d1);
    let d2 = new Date().setDate(this.view.dayCurrent.getDate() + 1);
    this.view.dayAfter = new Date(d2)

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{view.dayBefore}}</p>
  <p>{{view.dayCurrent}}</p>
  <p>{{view.dayAfter}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I am getting time stamps. I think I will create some computed properties and make desired strings out of this.

Comment: please check my updated answer i did some changes like using directly the constructeur of Date not the setDate method